# Code Optimization for groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the below code that basically performs a group by operation, followed by a sum.

```
grouped = df.groupby(by=['Cabin'], as_index=False)['Fare'].sum()
```

I then rename the columns

```
grouped.columns = ['Cabin', 'testCol']
```

And I then merge the "grouped" dataframe with my original dataframe to calculate aggregate.

```
df2 = df.merge(grouped, on='Cabin')
```

What this does is to populate my initial dataframe with the 'testCol' from my "grouped" dataframe.

Can this code be optimized to fit in one line or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems need [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new column of `sum`s:

```
df['testCol'] = df.groupby('Cabin')['Fare'].transform('sum')
```